# WSO2 ESB turns my '&' into '&amp;' when i launch a scheduled task, so link doesn't work

Tags: xml, apache-axis, code-formatting, ampersand, wso2-esb

Working with WSO2 ESB i try to save proxy service's xml with the correct character '&' instead of '&amp', but when i launch the task it always auto-saves file with '&amp'. 
In this way my link is always

```
"www.mysite.com/data?param1=myparam1&amp;param2=myParam2"
```

instead of the correct working form,

```
"www.mysite.com/data?param1=myParam1&param2=myParam2"
```

I think to modify the messageFormatter in axis2.xml, but i don't know hot to solve it.

Any idea?

Comment: When you say the link "doesn't work", what exactly are you doing and how does it fail? An ampersand in XML must be escaped as `&amp;`, otherwise it isn't XML, and any consumer of the XML should do the necessary unescaping.

Comment: Can you please provide proxy code where the &amp; is being replaced. Are you editing with eclipse or in the management console?

Answer (score 0):

In XML, `&` indicates the start of a character reference.

`&amp;` is the character reference for "an ampersand" and will be converted back into an ampersand when the XML is parsed.

`&param2=` is invalid XML and should cause an XML parser to abort with an exception.

If you have a problem, it is with the tool *reading* the XML, not the tool creating it.